# How to show row ordinal number w/ ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

Trying to show the index ("ordinal number") of the row with the [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com) library.

By ordinal number, I simply mean the row number if you count from top to bottom (based on reordering from drag'drop or any sorting that has been applied).

i.e. according to the screenshot attached, I'd like to see Porche having Index=0, Toyota=1 and Ford=2 after dragging "Porche" up to the top (c.f. the 'before'). But they index doesn't seem to get recalculated upon reordering.

[image: before/after reordering]

Here's what I've tried (see `_getIndexValue`):

```
import { Grid, GridOptions, ColDef } from "ag-grid/main";
import { ValueGetterParams } from "ag-grid/dist/lib/entities/colDef";

// for ag-grid-enterprise users only
import 'ag-grid-enterprise/main';

import "ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";

class SimpleGrid {
    _getIdValue(args: ValueGetterParams): any {
        return args.node.id;
    }

    _getIndexValue(args: ValueGetterParams): any {
        return args.node.rowIndex;
    }    

    private gridOptions: GridOptions = <GridOptions>{};

    constructor() {
        this.gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: this.createColumnDefs(),
            rowData: this.createRowData(),
            rowDragManaged: true,
        };

        let eGridDiv:HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('myGrid');
        new Grid(eGridDiv, this.gridOptions);
    }

    // specify the columns
    private createColumnDefs(): ColDef[] {
        return [
            {headerName: "Index", valueGetter: (args) => this._getIndexValue(args), rowDrag: true},            
            {headerName: "ID", valueGetter: (args) => this._getIdValue(args)},
            {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
            {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
            {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
        ];
    }

    // specify the data
    private createRowData() {
        return [
            {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
            {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
            {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
        ];
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    new SimpleGrid();
});
```

I'm hoping there's a better way to do it than subscribing to the dragEnd event and force-updating the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation (as I originally posted) works **if** you subscribe to the `RowDragEnd` event & invoke `api.refreshCells()`. It's probably not ideal from a performance perspective however for my purposes it won't matter.